# Why is this column unknown in ON clause?

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have the following statement:

```
SELECT
  p1.order_id,
  p1.job_id,
  j1.`status` AS p1_status
FROM
  wildcard_orders AS p1,
  wildcard_orders AS p2
LEFT JOIN wildcard_jobs AS j1 ON p1.job_id = j1.id
LEFT JOIN wildcard_jobs AS j2 ON p2.job_id = j2.id 
WHERE
  p1.order_id = p2.order_id 
  AND p1.job_id != p2.job_id
```

Basically, I am trying to get duplicate `order_id` that have a different `job_id` in the same table.

I've narrowed it down to including the same table in the `FROM` clause but I am sure I have done this before!

The exact error I get back is:

```
1054 - Unknown column 'p1.job_id' in 'on clause'
```

Can anyone help with why?

Comment: Change where criteria to `inner join`.

Comment: @Forward This didn't work. And I assume you meant change the `LEFT JOIN` to `INNER JOIN`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT
  p1.order_id,
  p1.job_id,
  j1.`status` AS p1_status
FROM
  wildcard_orders AS p1
INNER JOIN wildcard_orders AS p2 ON p1.order_id = p2.order_id
LEFT JOIN wildcard_jobs AS j1 ON p1.job_id = j1.id
LEFT JOIN wildcard_jobs AS j2 ON p2.job_id = j2.id 
WHERE p1.job_id != p2.job_id
```

***NOTE***: Do not use comma to join tables and explicit `join` syntax at same time.

Comment: Nailed it. Cheers!